# Why would the Windows Android Studio Emulator suddenly become slow when accessing firebase on a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, android-emulator

I am testing a flutter app in the emulator in Android Studio. The app and emulator had no issues a few days ago. Suddenly, the app is painfully slow in a couple of areas:

- The emulator no longer auto-boots the app. After `Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...`, nothing happens. But the app is installed, and if the app is run manually, the debugger starts logging.
- On initial load where the user logs in to firebase auth, or when already logged in and the app goes through that verification. This takes about 5-10 minutes on an emulator, and about two seconds on a physical device (and was previously this fast on the emulator).
- Occasionally firestore realtime updates don't happen, but are usually very slow

A few troubleshooting notes:

- Emulator itself does not appear slow (i.e. no visible lag, and loading spinner is regular speed)
- I have fully uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled.
- System has 8 core CPU, 64GB RAM, modern GPU, SSD
- Emulator device is allocated 8GB RAM, 512MB heap, 3GB local storage
- Android studio and plugins are latest version
- Emulator network speed is set to full
- This issue occurs on Windows. It runs normally on Mac Android Studio Emulator

Comment: Note this occurs with API 33. I have discovered with API 32 that the app installs and launches properly, however the lag still remains.

Comment: It's not just flutter. Native apps are seeing the same issue. Extremely slow network speed on Windows 10 Android emulators. Tested with API 29, 31, 32.

Comment: This appears to be a firebase issue, though (and as I mentioned has worked fine until a few days ago). Other network requests are fine, and using Chrome on the emulator is good. Speed test shows almost full network speeds and very low latency.

Comment: I though I was going crazy. Any idea what might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be fixed with the latest stable Android Emulator release, `v31.3.11-9058569`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue with the recent versions of Android Emulator on Windows platform. Downgrade the version of Android Emulator to **31.2.9**.
You can download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive).

Procedure of manual installation of custom version of Android Emulator is given in the link above.

Edit: This issue is fixed in latest version(31.3.x) of Android Emulator.